# HttpHandler template in Xamarin

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, httphandler

Visual Studio has a HttpHandler template.
I didn't find that template online.
How to create simple ASP.NET HttpHandler using Xamarin?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add new solution choosing "Empty ASP.NET Project" template.
2. Add new file to project choosing "Web Handler with CodeBehind" template.
3. Add new file to project choosing "Web Application Configuration" template.
4. In `web.config` file replace `httpHandlers` section with
5. Add `context.Response.Write ("It works!");` into `ProcessRequest` method
6. Hit F5

It should open new browser tab on `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` with "It works!".